# Install USB wifi card TL-WN823N in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: drivers, wireless

I'm trying to install the drivers of my new USB wifi card, and I'm getting this problem:

```
$ sudo make
[sudo] password for lucia: 
"******************************************"
"NO SKRC,we will use default KSRC"
"******************************************"
make ARCH=x86_64 CROSS_COMPILE= -C /lib/modules/4.10.0-40-generic/build=/home/lucia/Descargas/TL-WN823NEU_V2_160315_Linux/Driver  modules
make[1]: se entra en el directorio '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.10.0-40-generic'
"******************************************"
"NO SKRC,we will use default KSRC"
"******************************************"
  CC [M]  /home/lucia/Descargas/TL-WN823NEU_V2_160315_Linux/Driver/core/rtw_cmd.o
In file included from /home/lucia/Descargas/TL-WN823NEU_V2_160315_Linux/Driver/include/drv_types.h:95:0,
             from /home/lucia/Descargas/TL-WN823NEU_V2_160315_Linux/Driver/core/rtw_cmd.c:22:
/home/lucia/Descargas/TL-WN823NEU_V2_160315_Linux/Driver/include/hal_com.h:413:13: error: ‘file_path’ redeclared as different kind of symbol
 extern char file_path[PATH_LENGTH_MAX];
         ^
In file included from ./include/linux/seq_file.h:10:0,
             from ./include/linux/pinctrl/consumer.h:17,
             from ./include/linux/pinctrl/devinfo.h:21,
             from ./include/linux/device.h:24,
             from ./include/linux/dmaengine.h:20,
             from ./include/linux/netdevice.h:38,
             from /home/lucia/Descargas/TL-WN823NEU_V2_160315_Linux/Driver/include/osdep_service_linux.h:35,
             from /home/lucia/Descargas/TL-WN823NEU_V2_160315_Linux/Driver/include/osdep_service.h:41,
             from /home/lucia/Descargas/TL-WN823NEU_V2_160315_Linux/Driver/include/drv_types.h:32,
             from /home/lucia/Descargas/TL-WN823NEU_V2_160315_Linux/Driver/core/rtw_cmd.c:22:
./include/linux/fs.h:2680:14: note: previous declaration of ‘file_path’ was here
 extern char *file_path(struct file *, char *, int);
              ^
In file included from /home/lucia/Descargas/TL-WN823NEU_V2_160315_Linux/Driver/include/drv_types.h:65:0,
             from /home/lucia/Descargas/TL-WN823NEU_V2_160315_Linux/Driver/core/rtw_cmd.c:22:
/home/lucia/Descargas/TL-WN823NEU_V2_160315_Linux/Driver/core/rtw_cmd.c: In function ‘btinfo_evt_dump’:
/home/lucia/Descargas/TL-WN823NEU_V2_160315_Linux/Driver/include/rtw_debug.h:187:19: error: void value not ignored as it ought to be
#define _seqdump seq_printf
                   ^
/home/lucia/Descargas/TL-WN823NEU_V2_160315_Linux/Driver/include/rtw_debug.h:242:7: note: in expansion of macro ‘_seqdump’
    if(_seqdump(sel, fmt, ##arg)) /*rtw_warn_on(1)*/; \
       ^
/home/lucia/Descargas/TL-WN823NEU_V2_160315_Linux/Driver/core/rtw_cmd.c:3293:2: note: in expansion of macro ‘DBG_871X_SEL_NL’
  DBG_871X_SEL_NL(sel, "cid:0x%02x, len:%u\n", info->cid, info->len);
      ^
/home/lucia/Descargas/TL-WN823NEU_V2_160315_Linux/Driver/include/rtw_debug.h:187:19: error: void value not ignored as it ought to be
  #define _seqdump seq_printf
                   ^
/home/lucia/Descargas/TL-WN823NEU_V2_160315_Linux/Driver/include/rtw_debug.h:242:7: note: in expansion of macro ‘_seqdump’
if(_seqdump(sel, fmt, ##arg)) /*rtw_warn_on(1)*/; \
       ^
/home/lucia/Descargas/TL-WN823NEU_V2_160315_Linux/Driver/core/rtw_cmd.c:3296:3: note: in expansion of macro ‘DBG_871X_SEL_NL’
   DBG_871X_SEL_NL(sel, "byte2:%s%s%s%s%s%s%s%s\n"
      ^
/home/lucia/Descargas/TL-WN823NEU_V2_160315_Linux/Driver/include/rtw_debug.h:187:19: error: void value not ignored as it ought to be
  #define _seqdump seq_printf
                   ^
/home/lucia/Descargas/TL-WN823NEU_V2_160315_Linux/Driver/include/rtw_debug.h:242:7: note: in expansion of macro ‘_seqdump’
if(_seqdump(sel, fmt, ##arg)) /*rtw_warn_on(1)*/; \
       ^
/home/lucia/Descargas/TL-WN823NEU_V2_160315_Linux/Driver/core/rtw_cmd.c:3308:3: note: in expansion of macro ‘DBG_871X_SEL_NL’
   DBG_871X_SEL_NL(sel, "retry_cnt:%u\n", info->retry_cnt);
       ^
/home/lucia/Descargas/TL-WN823NEU_V2_160315_Linux/Driver/include/rtw_debug.h:187:19: error: void value not ignored as it ought to be
  #define _seqdump seq_printf
                   ^
/home/lucia/Descargas/TL-WN823NEU_V2_160315_Linux/Driver/include/rtw_debug.h:242:7: note: in expansion of macro ‘_seqdump’
if(_seqdump(sel, fmt, ##arg)) /*rtw_warn_on(1)*/; \
       ^
/home/lucia/Descargas/TL-WN823NEU_V2_160315_Linux/Driver/core/rtw_cmd.c:3311:3: note: in expansion of macro ‘DBG_871X_SEL_NL’
   DBG_871X_SEL_NL(sel, "rssi:%u\n", info->rssi);
       ^
/home/lucia/Descargas/TL-WN823NEU_V2_160315_Linux/Driver/include/rtw_debug.h:187:19: error: void value not ignored as it ought to be
  #define _seqdump seq_printf
                   ^
/home/lucia/Descargas/TL-WN823NEU_V2_160315_Linux/Driver/include/rtw_debug.h:242:7: note: in expansion of macro ‘_seqdump’
if(_seqdump(sel, fmt, ##arg)) /*rtw_warn_on(1)*/; \
       ^
/home/lucia/Descargas/TL-WN823NEU_V2_160315_Linux/Driver/core/rtw_cmd.c:3314:3: note: in expansion of macro ‘DBG_871X_SEL_NL’
   DBG_871X_SEL_NL(sel, "byte5:%s%s\n"
   ^
scripts/Makefile.build:294: fallo en las instrucciones para el objetivo '/home/lucia/Descargas/TL-WN823NEU_V2_160315_Linux/Driver/core/rtw_cmd.o'
make[2]: *** [/home/lucia/Descargas/TL-WN823NEU_V2_160315_Linux/Driver/core/rtw_cmd.o] Error 1
Makefile:1524: fallo en las instrucciones para el objetivo '_module_/home/lucia/Descargas/TL-WN823NEU_V2_160315_Linux/Driver'
make[1]: *** [_module_/home/lucia/Descargas/TL-WN823NEU_V2_160315_Linux/Driver] Error 2
make[1]: se sale del directorio '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.10.0-40-generic'
 Makefile:1696: fallo en las instrucciones para el objetivo 'modules'
make: *** [modules] Error 2
```

this is what I get with the command lsusb:

```
$ lsusb
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0bda:0129 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTS5129 Card Reader Controller
Bus 001 Device 003: ID b49a:04f2  
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0bda:57b5 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 2357:0109  
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Comment: Please edit your question to add the result of the terminal command: `lsusb` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: all that is the result after I write sudo make

Comment: We will be very happy to help you if we can identify the exact device from the terminal command lsusb.

Comment: ok, I just edited the question with the requiered output

Answer (score 0):

With a working internet connection, open a terminal and do:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install git
git clone https://github.com/Mange/rtl8192eu-linux-driver.git
cd rtl8192eu-linux-driver
sudo dkms add .
sudo dkms install rtl8192eu/1.0
sudo modprobe 8192eu
```

Your wireless should now be working